# NameError: global name 'GetID' is not defined

Tags: python, nameerror

I'm getting an error in this line:

```
chartNode.AddArray(pairs[0], pairs[1], GetID())
```

Stating:

```
NameError: global name 'GetID' is not defined
```

Does that mean I have to have a function definition for `GetID()`?

Thanks.

Comment: yes? Are you using a specific library or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. The error is telling you that you are calling a function that doesn't exist. You must either define it, or import it from somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Yup!  It means that inside of that current scope you don't have a definition for a function called GetId so it doesn't know what that means.